# I want to use the function EllipticE( ), ElliptctcF( ) EllipticK( ) functions used in Wolfram in R

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, integral, wolframalpha

I have installed the  pracma package, and I know there is a function is called ellipke() in R,this can be used in the same way as EllipticE() and EllipticF() in Wolfram, These functions are used for solving elliptical integrals, but the way to use these functions **in Walfram**  is with two arguments for example like this:

`EllipticK[2,3]`, mathematically is E(2|3).First I need to use a function like EllipticK() in R.
 Second I could used ellipke() (in R) like if I using EllipticE() and EllipticF() in Wolfram but only with one argument, for example in **Wolfram** is EllipticE(2,1) but in **R** just allow me  do `ellipke(2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Carlson` package:

```
> Carlson::elliptic_E(2,3)
[1] 0.475224+1.591887i
```

This is identical to [EllipticE[2,3]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=EllipticE%5B2%2C3%5D).

`EllipticK` is the complete elliptic integral of first kind:

```
EllipticK[x] = EllipticF[Pi/2,x]
```

With `Carlson`:

```
> Carlson::elliptic_F(pi/2,3)
[1] 1.001077-1.17142i
```

Identical to [EllipticK[3]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=EllipticK%5B3%5D).

Comment: just one more thing,  when I can use just one argument like in **wolfram **  EllipticE(2)     the equivalent in **R ** whit elliptic_E would be ?

Comment: @DiegoAndresBurgos This is `elliptic_E(pi/2,2)`.